# Handling integrals of trig functions

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I'm not sure how to handle the following class of integrals:

$I=\int_0^{2\pi}f(\cos(\theta))d\theta$

If I make the change of variables $x=\cos(\theta)$ the new limits of the integral are the same, giving $I=0$. I know this is incorrect, as it fails for the case $f(\cos(\theta))=\cos^2(\theta)$, for example.

Can anybody tell me where the inconsistency is here, please?

My *guess* is that it comes down to $\theta=\arccos(x)$ not being well defined, or something of that nature.

Comment: I believe I have answered my own question: the problem is that $x=\cos(\theta)$ is implicitly defining $\theta=\arccos(x)$ which is a multivalued function. Usually we would restrict it onto a range $0<\theta<\pi$ where it has its principle value. Clearly $0<\theta<2\pi$ wont work here. All is not lost though. First let $\theta\to\theta-\pi$ (now the integral is on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Then notice $\cos(\theta-\pi)=-\cos(\theta)$.Then use the fact that the integrand is even (because $\cos(\theta)$ is even), so we have an integral on $[0,\pi]$ and are free to make the substitution $x=\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not properly answer my own question on SE. If somebody wants to leave an answer confirming/denying what I have written above I will consider it for the accepted answer (for the sake of people who have the same issue in the future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change of variables should be in the form not $x=g(θ)$, but $\theta=g(x)$, so you should fix a branch $g$ of the multivalued function $\arccos$.